# Return matching rows only SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sure this simple but i am really stuck. Here is a example of the resultset i want from two tables that have the same structure and in this case data or  records

TableA

```
 Ref  cola  colb id
 ------------------
 1     a      b   14
 1     a      b   24
```

TableB

```
Ref  cola  colb id
------------------
 1     a      b  1
 1     a      b  2
 1     a      b  3
```

Expected result:

```
Ref  cola  colb id Ref1  cola1 colb1 id1
----------------------------------------
1      a     b   14  1      a      b   1
1      a     b   24  1      a      b   2
```

Comment: TableA has 2 rows while TableB has 3 rows. Why results include only 2 rows?

Comment: it doesn't have to be 2 rows necessarily it can be 3 rows with the 3rd row in TableA having NULL values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.Ref =t2.Ref AND t1.cola = t2.cola
   AND t1.colb = t2.colb AND t1.id = t2.id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
USING ( Ref , cola , colb, id )
```

Answer (score 1):

one more way would be

```
;with cte
as
(
select Ref, cola,  colb, id,
hashbytes('sha1',concat(Ref, cola,  colb)) as tb1hash
from table1
)
 select 
 t1.Ref, --all required cols
 from cte c
join
(
select Ref, cola,  colb, id,
hashbytes('sha1',concat(Ref, cola,  colb)) as tb2hash
from table2
) b
on
b.tb2hash=c.tb1hash
```

Comment: You should at least add separator between concatenated columns to avoid colisions.

Comment: @lad2025:i think ,this will not produce collisions,for sha1 to produce a collision,it took many years .."6,610 years of processor time"  https://www.theregister.co.uk/2017/02/23/google_first_sha1_collision/

Comment: I mean concat like `11 2` and `1 12` will produce the same. Where `11|2` <> `1|12`

Answer (score 0):

Guessing:

```
;WITH TableAWithRowNum
AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.TableA
), TableBWithRowNum
AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNum
FROM dbo.TableB
)
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM TableAWithRowNum a 
INNER JOIN TableBWithRowNum b ON a.Ref = b.Ref 
--AND other join predicates on ColA, ... etc.
AND a.RowNum = b.RowNum
```

Comment: In order to get all rows from both tables, instead of INNER JOIN I would use FULL OUTER JOIN.